# error - Exception thrown at 0x7C0708F0 in the copy constructor and not able to run the program

Tags: c++

I am trying to run the `C++` code and getting the error in the copy constructor.

The error is-

> Exception thrown at 0x7C0708F0 (ucrtbased.dll): 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

```
// Default constructor
Token::Token()
{
    text = NULL;   // default constructor creates an empty C-String
}


// Explicit normal Constructor
Token::Token(const char* newtoken, int LineNumber) // const is not applied please check
{
    text = new char[strlen(newtoken) + 1];
    strcpy(text, newtoken);
    
    number_list.pushBack(LineNumber);
}

//Copy Constructor
Token::Token(const Token& token)
{
    int len = strlen(token.text);    -----> error on this line
    text = new char[len + 1];
    *text = *token.text;
}
```

Below is code of header file for the above code is-
(only the required part of the code is showing otherwise it is a very long program)

```
class Token
{
private:
    char* text{ };  //pointer to array of characters
    IntList number_list;  // manages the list of numbers

public:

    Token(const char*, int); // const is not applied please check
    Token();
    Token(const Token&); // copy constructor
    Token(Token&&); // move constructor
    Token& operator=(const Token& rhs); // copy assignment constructor
```

Comment: What do you expect? If you are copying a default constructed `Token`, then you `text` of the default constructed `Token` would be `NULL` and the copy constructor would try to read from that address when you call `strlen`.

Comment: Using Stack Overflow as your debugger is the slowest way to debug a program.  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

you should just switch for std::string, idk. Unless it's forbidden for some reason.